# Javascript / SAPUI5 : Binding a JSONArray to a ListItem

Tags: javascript, json, data-binding, sapui5, listitem

i've a SAPUI5-App to view data from a DBMS:
DMBS <-> Java <-> jsp -> ajax -> JSONModel <-> SAPUI5
I've a problem with a model with this structure:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "value_a",
    "key2": "value_b",
    "key3": "value_c",
  },
  {
    "key1": "value_d",
    "key2": "value_e",
    "key3": "value_f",
  },
...
]
```

This data are stored in a model defined in my manifest.json. 
Now i want to show this data in a list. In my view i define a list in the createContent function and add it to my page.
In the controller i try to bind the data to a listitem:

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.InputListItem({
   label : "{Model>}"
}),
oList.bindItems("Model>/", oItemTemplate);
```

In this try there are the correct count of listitems corresponding the number of objects in my model. But in the list are only "Objects"

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk4ca.png)

My plan ist to show a merged text from one object in one listitem:

- Item 1 : "value_a value_b value_c"
- Item 2 : "value_d value_e value_d"
- ...

Now i use a formatter for the label.

```
label : {
    path : "Model>/",
    formatter : function(data) {

        return data;
    }
}
```

According to this code new the list shown still the correct number of items and each item contains all ojects

[List with formatter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYDY5.png)

But how i can access my object data key1, key2 and key3? All my trys are unsuccessful

```
console.log(data.key1) -> undefined

console.log(data/key1) -> ReferenceError: key1 is not defined
```

Can anyone help me please?

Regards

MacLeod

PS:
If i use

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.InputListItem({
    label : "{Model>key1}"
});
oList.bindItems("Model>/", oItemTemplate);
```

then value_a / value_d will be shown on the listitems.
But i can't use this with the formatter

In the formatter

```
formatter : function(data) {

   return data;
}
```

the data-object contains the complete JSON data. But there is no automatic iteration like using normal binding

```
label : "{Model>key1}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.InputListItem({
    label : {
    parts : [
        { path : "Model>key1" },
        { path : "Model>key2"}
    ],
    formatter : function(key1, key2) {
        return key1 + " " + key2;
    }
}
oList.bindItems("Model>/", oItemTemplate);
```

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3517535

Comment: just a comment

    parts : [
          { path : "Model>key1" },
          { path : "Model>key2"}
    ],

can be just
    parts : [ "Model>key1", "Model>key2" ],

Answer (score 0):

In your picture of your list, you can see, that every line is a list of objects. In this objects you can access the keys. So in the first, you have to access the objects, which is like `data[0]` or `data[1]` and so on. I think you miss one step in the hierarchy.

Comment: Sure you are right. But the formatter don't iterate automaticly. 
If is use a formatter like this

label : {
 path : "Model>/",
 formatter : function(data) {
  var text="";
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   text += data[i].key1 + " " + data[i].key2 + " " + data[i].key3;
  }
  return text;
 }
}

there is in the end only one listitem containing with all value in one label and not the number of listitems corresponding the number of elements in the array